# How to print 2 conecutive lines from a file in python?

Tags: bioinformatics

I have a list of words in a file (PDB IDs). I want to compare the IDs to another file containing protein sequences in FASTA format. But, the PDB ID and the sequence are in consecutive lines. How to print both the lines together?

Comment: You should probably give a short example of what you would like to achieve. That said, I would suggest you to look at a tool called bioawk (https://github.com/lh3/bioawk), and especially its `-c fastx` option, which makes it convenient to access header and sequence in a fasta or fastq file and redisplay  them on the same line: `bioawk -c fastx '{print $name,$seq}' proteins.fasta`

Comment: I agree with @bli — giving a concrete example of exactly what output you want would be helpful here. I will add that you may not necessarily need anything as complicated as `bioawk`; if you simply need to pull matching header/sequence pairs from the FASTA, you can do something like `grep -F -f <pdb_file> -A 1 --no-group-separator <fasta>` (for example, assuming you have access to `grep`)